# TypeScript : Initialize a member with another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In a `TypeScript 2.2.2` project, I have the following configuration :

```
export const MAIN_CONFIG: AppConfig = {

    REST_API_BASE_ENDPOINT: 'api/v1',
    REST_API_SECURITY_ENDPOINT: this.REST_API_BASE_ENDPOINT + '/security/test',
}
```

I expected that at runtime `REST_API_SECURITY_ENDPOINT` value will be `api/v1/security/test` but I got `undefined/security/test`

Is there any way to initialize a `const` member with another ?

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK "this" is in context of a class, here the class is AppConfig so the initialization parameters ```REST_API_BASE_ENDPOINT``` will not be available as ```this.REST_API_BASE_ENDPOINT``` until the instance has been initialized

Comment: @SuryaPratap: That's not a class, it's just an object initializer.

Comment: @Crowder The answer you proposed does not work !

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am not very sure of how object initalizers work, but I am pretty sure that ```this``` is generally used to refer to a function context in javascript

Comment: @SuryaPratap: No, what `this` means depends on where it's used. At global scope, `this` is a reference to the global object. In a module, `this` is `undefined` (I think). In a non-arrow function, it's whatever it was set to when that function was called.